# What does Amazon.com's "Kindle Edition" actually mean?

Tags: amazon, kindle

I understand *Kindle* to be a brand name of a tablet computer. Does this mean that if I buy the "Kindle Edition" of a book I won't be able to read it on my PC or Samsung tablet?

I want to be sure that I'll be able to read "Kindle Edition" of a book *without* having a Kindle device. Is this possible?

Comment: Sadly the answers here are not very useful. If you have an *,epub file without DRM protection you can read it on the PC with the free Sumatra PDF reader.

Comment: the short answer is:  **yes** you can read a kindle book purchased through amazon on a web browser.  usually.

Comment: the kindle doesn't support epub @Elmue but you can try other e-readers.  or, just convert the `epub` to `mobi`.  you might want to ask a question like "how do I read ___ on my kindle?" if that's the problem.  merry christmas, I'm inferring you just got a kindle.  it's proprietary tech, designed for lock-in to amazon.  the website "read.amazon.com" is not exactly the same as a physical kindle.

Comment: In the mean time I found out that it is very easy to read an EPUB book on Kindle. It is obvious that Amazon wants you to read only their content which brings them cash. But if you have an EPUB bought anywhere else you can use the free software Calibre which converts and uploads your book to a Kindle.

Answer (score 7):

Kindle is the brand name of a range of e-readers and tablets (called Kindle Fire) produced by Amazon. Typically books bought as a Kindle Edition will be downloaded directed to a Kindle device attached to your Amazon account.

If you want to read Kindle Edition books on a Samsung tablet or desktop PC then you'll need to download the Kindle app for your device. There is an [Android version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.kindle) and a [PC version](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000426311), as well as [several other options](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/?ie=UTF8&docId=1000493771).

You can click the "Read with Our Free App" or "Read on Any Device" (or similar text) link below the price for an overview and links to more detailed information.

[image: Kindle Edition options]

Comment: Therefore Kindle is also a name of an app. Right? Not just a range of e-readers and tablets.

Comment: @Celeritas, Kindle  is also [the name of the format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats#KF8_.28Amazon_Kindle.29). You can take the kindle and convert it to pdf using instructions from http://zacwe.st/blog/kindle-to-epub/#fn1. Also http://arstechnica.com/gandgets/2012/10/drm-be-damned-how-to-protect-your-amazon-e-books-from-being-deleted/

Answer (score 1):

To clarify and expand on Andrew's answer:

Manage content through `amazon.com/myk` where you can view items and organize into collections.

Use `read.amazon.com` to read material from a browser.

Or, use the `kindle` app on phone or tablet to both manage and read content.

It's not quite, but almost, a 1:1 relationship between an e-ink kindle device and the cloud.  Most everything will be synced and available both.  Changing or re-organizing on either will sync to the other.

You don't **need** to buy a Kindle e-ink device, or Kindle tablet.  You might *want* to, at some point.  This is DRM lock-in analogous to iTunes et. al. so that once you pick your poison it's just easier to stay in that walled garden.

(For what it's worth, take a look at e-ink readers-- very interesting.)

--

You can delete material from a device and leave it on the cloud reader.  Or, delete from both device and cloud.

Some material, here and there, won't show on your e-ink device because it's not compatible.  Not an issue for this Kindle user, and a very minor "gotcha".

---

useful links:

https://ebook.online-convert.com/

https://calibre-ebook.com/

https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle

https://www.fivefilters.org/

Comment: Your answer is still too superficial for me. I bought an e-book (extension *.epub) and loaded it via USB to the folder "documents" on the Kindle but it does not appear on screen. eBooks seem to exist in version for Kindle and "not for Kindle". Is that right? Please explain with much more details. Your answer is not very useful.

Comment: you need to convert you `epub` document to `mobi` for which you can use an online service or `calibre` as **kindle does not support epub**.    once converted to `mobi` you can just e-mail the `mobi` document to yourself and it'll show under "documents".  does that help?